# Can a objects method be called before a object is fully created?

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

I got a crash report from a user with seems rather impossible. The stacktrace indicate that a object was null and he got a nullpointerException.

(here is the line if you want to see)

```
public class City extends Unit {
    private ArrayList<SolderType> Queue = new ArrayList<SolderType>();

    public float getPrecentCompleted()
    {
        if(Queue.isEmpty())
        {
            return 0f;
        }
        //More code that is not relevent
    }
}
```

It doesn't leave out much to interpret Queue was probably null, however Queue is only create at one place in my code and that is in the constructor. So i don't see how it can be null. The object is shared over more then one thread and new objects are created all the time. But the Queue point can only be set at the creation of the object. So i don't see how this is possible. Is it possible for one thread to call on a objects method while an other is created the object but not done?

**EDIT** Added some more code that might be relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, unless you've added synchronisation to prevent it.

Comment: Maybe. But maybe it should just be final or volatile. And since it's only assigned at creation, it should be final.

Comment: It would be nice to see the constructor body as well as full exception stack trace.

Comment: I agree with @TagirValeev, please show all relevant code.

Comment: Does anyone know if happens-before is established on existing a constructor? I know it was a goal of JSR-133, but I'm not sure if it's the case.

Comment: There's a happens-before but only in the same thread or for final fields. OP, the term you're looking for is "unsafe publication".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment gives the correct answer: Yes, that is possible, unless you've added synchronisation to prevent it. The only operations wich define an order between two threads are the following (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

1. An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock
   actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the
   synchronization order).
2. A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all
   subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined
   according to the synchronization order).
3. An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in
   the thread it starts.
4. The write of the default value (zero, false, or null) to each
   variable synchronizes-with the first action in every thread. Although it may seem a little strange to write a default value to a variable before the object containing the variable is allocated, conceptually every object is created at the start of the program with its default initialized values.
5. The final action in a thread T1 synchronizes-with any action in
   another thread T2 that detects that T1 has terminated.
6. If thread T1 interrupts thread T2, the interrupt by T1
   synchronizes-with any point where any other thread (including T2)
   determines that T2 has been interrupted (by having an
   InterruptedException thrown or by invoking Thread.interrupted or
   Thread.isInterrupted).

Without such an operation you will see the object in other threads in an undefined state.

On way to solve the null pointer exception is to use a final field (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5). But you must also synchronize ArrayList. I suggest to use a queue from the java.util.concurrent package.

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause for such situation is calling an overridden method from superclass constructor like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NPEInheritance {
    static class Parent {
        Parent() {
            validate();
        }

        void validate() {}
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {
        private ArrayList<Object> Queue;

        Child() {
            Queue = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        void validate() {
            if(Queue.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Queue is empty");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child();
    }
}
```

When you run this code, you will see such "impossible `NullPointerException`". As you can see, here `Parent` constructor calls method which is overridden in `Child` class and overridden method uses the field which is not initialized yet as `Child` constructor has still not executed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but this is not the problem here as it is created where it is declared and is included in all constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you create the Child Object the first thing it does its to initializate the parent Object (because it extends) and when your parent object tries to validate its twhen you get NullPointer.
I think you need to put your Queue object into the parent something like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NPEInheritance {
    static class Parent {

        protected ArrayList<Object> Queue;

        Parent() {
            Queue = new ArrayList<>();
            validate();
        }

        void validate() {}
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {

        Child() {
        }

        @Override
        void validate() {
            if(Queue.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Queue is empty");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A particular case to watch out for arises when class A's static  initialization creates or references a (possibly static) instance of class B, and B's static initialization has a similar dependency on A.

Obviously, in this situation neither class can fully initialize before the other.

Java silently breaks the deadlock by allowing one of the classes to return uninitialized values. As a result, with no warning, you may see "impossible" zeros or nulls. Since this dependency loop may go through several other classes it can be a real pain to track down even if you know this risk exists.

The fix is generally to refactor some or all of the static objects involved into a third class, making the dependency graph a tree again. Easy and obvious once you're found the problem.  Better, of course, to avoid creating the problem in the first place.